# how to speedup this opencv python code?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

```
`import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_, back = cap.read()
back=cv2.cvtColor(back,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
back = cv2.GaussianBlur(back,(5,5),0)
ret,back = cv2.threshold(back,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
#back = cv2.erode(th2,kernel,iterations = 3)
while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, video = cap.read()

    img=cv2.cvtColor(video,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
    ret,mask1 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    #kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    #mask1 = cv2.erode(th3,kernel,iterations = 3)
    mask=mask1
    #img2=cv2.bitwise_and(mask1,back,mask = mask)
    #mask=mask-img2
    final=np.zeros((480,640,1), np.uint8)
    m=0
    n=0

    for i in range (477):
        c=0
        for j in range(637):
            if abs(back[i,j]-mask[i,j])<5:
                mask.itemset(i,j,0)
                if mask.item(i,j)==mask.item(i,j+1):
                    continue
                if c==0:
                    m=j
                    c=c+1
                    continue

                if c==1:
                    n=j+1
                    #print i,(m+n)//2
                    final.itemset(i,(m+n)//2,0,255)

    '''cv2.namedWindow('subtracted',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('subtracted', mask1)
    '''
    cv2.namedWindow('actual',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('actual', mask)
    '''cv2.namedWindow('initial',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('initial', back)
    '''
    cv2.namedWindow('final',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('final', final)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

iam writing this for 3d scanning.it has to background subtract and give a thin laser line.
It is taking lot of time and is giving a runtime error(overflow encountered in ubytes scalars).can we optimise this?

Comment: you are probably trying to store something out of range inside the `if (c==1)` block, when you sum n+m (j+j+1 would be the minimum value, and j goes up to 637). Did you check that?

Comment: Rather than iterating over all the pixels in a frame (those two nested for loops), you need to make use of the operations numpy provides on the arrays. Those are implemented in C, with the loops optimized in many ways, and much much faster. e.g. `np.absolute(back - mask) < 5` returns a matrix of bools.

Comment: BTW, can you attach a sample frame or two from your input data, for people to test it with?

Comment: For example, you could use [something like this](http://pastebin.com/8EAhSvvS) to reduce the image to a list of coordinates satisfying the conditions in the two nested loops + two nested ifs. That should be a lot less to process with Python only.